# CNN Classifier only guesses one thing - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification

I'm trying to make a model predict the race of a 75x75 image's ethnicity, but when ever I train the model, the accuracy always stays completely still at 53.2%. I didn't realize why until I actually ran it on some of photos. It turned out, that no matter what the photo was, it would always predict 'other'. I'm not entirely sure why though.

I copied the code over from [the official PyTorch Quickstart tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html), and in that dataset or the standard MNIST data, it worked fine. I changed the dataset to the [UTKFace](https://susanqq.github.io/UTKFace/), and then it started only predicting one label, all the time.

Here's my code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import torch.nn.functional as F

training_data = ImageFolder(
    root = "data_training/",
    transform = ToTensor(),
)

testing_data = ImageFolder(
    root = "data_testing/",
    transform = ToTensor()
)

training_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(testing_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1296, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 1024)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, 84)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(84, 5)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        
        
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x
    
model = NeuralNetwork().to("cpu")
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to("cpu"), y.to("cpu")
        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

def tests(dataloader, model):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to("cpu"), y.to("cpu")
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= size
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")

epochs = 10
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(training_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    tests(test_dataloader, model)

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")
```

The training logs:

```
Epoch 1
-------------------------------
loss: 1.628994  [    0/23705]
loss: 1.620698  [ 6400/23705]
loss: 1.615423  [12800/23705]
loss: 1.596390  [19200/23705]
Test Error: 
 Accuracy: 53.2%, Avg loss: 0.024725 

Epoch 2
-------------------------------
loss: 1.593613  [    0/23705]
loss: 1.581375  [ 6400/23705]
loss: 1.583656  [12800/23705]
loss: 1.591942  [19200/23705]
Test Error: 
 Accuracy: 53.2%, Avg loss: 0.024165 

Epoch 3
-------------------------------
loss: 1.541260  [    0/23705]
loss: 1.592345  [ 6400/23705]
loss: 1.540908  [12800/23705]
loss: 1.540741  [19200/23705]
Test Error: 
 Accuracy: 53.2%, Avg loss: 0.023705 

Epoch 4
-------------------------------
loss: 1.566888  [    0/23705]
loss: 1.524875  [ 6400/23705]
loss: 1.540764  [12800/23705]
loss: 1.510044  [19200/23705]
Test Error: 
 Accuracy: 53.2%, Avg loss: 0.023323 

Epoch 5
-------------------------------
loss: 1.530084  [    0/23705]
loss: 1.498773  [ 6400/23705]
loss: 1.537755  [12800/23705]
loss: 1.508989  [19200/23705]
Test Error: 
 Accuracy: 53.2%, Avg loss: 0.022993 
....
```

No matter how many epochs I set it to, or how many layers I add in to try to get it to overfit, it always just seems to guess the same thing over and over again, with no signs of improvement.

I separated the UTKFace dataset into folders based on the ethnicity category of the name. There are 23705 images in the training data and 10134 in the testing.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is my dataset not large enough? Are there not enough layers?

Comment: Is there a good reason to classify ethnicity? I would help, but ethics are really holding me back.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren oh i was just trying to emulate michael reeve's video on it for fun lol. not doing it to be racist or anything, sorry if it came across that way!

Comment: Fair enough, I'll come back to it later (with CelebA or something) if you're not able to figure out it by then. Please do keep ethics in mind as you do your AI research, there's a lot of shady stuff out there that really ought to be rebuked (e.g. Chinese institutions doing ethnicity recognition and helping to facilitate Uyghur genocide).

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I'll try to keep that in mind. this was just a fun little project inspired by one of my favorite content creators, but I understand the underlying ethical problems that this sort of AI research might bring.

Comment: Considering that you ran this on MNIST and are using the same model-structure (at least that is what I understood), and MNIST has to just look at 28x28 pixels while the model has to right now look at 75x75 pixels, it might be a bit overwhelmed for that.

Comment: @Canbach I changed the structure. Sorry about the misunderstanding!

Comment: If it is only predicting other class and you get 53% accuracy, that means 53% of test data is other class, and 47% is shared by 4 classes. So it seems data is imbalanced, where other class is about 5 times more than any other class. This is on the test set based on your description. If that imbalance is even worse in training set, it could be that the network is learning to classify any given input as 'other' since it is seen that the most.

Comment: @yutasrobot yeah, the dataset does appear to be imbalanced in this way. should I trim the number of photos in the 'other' section? or are there other solutions?

Comment: CrossEntropyLoss takes a weight parameter specifying loss weights for each class. You can either balance the training by assigning lower weights to 'other' class or for a quick test you can trim the 'other' class and see if the network is learning this way.

Answer (score 1):

The number of layers and the dataset size don't explain this behavior for this example. Your CNN is behaving as a constant function, so far I don't know why, but these might be some clues:

1. Since you have separated your data by label into folders, if you are training your model using only one of those folders you will obtain a constant function.
2. The last layer of your neural network has no activation function! This is, in method `forward` you are doing `x = self.fc5(x)` instead of `x = F.<function>(self.fc5(x))`.
3. Where do you indicate, when loading the training data, which is the label for each image? Are you sure that `training_dataloader` is loading the images with their correct label?

Comment: I added the activation function to the model, as you said, but it didn't appear to change anything. I know for sure that I am not training my model on only one of the folders, as I've browsed through the DataLoader, and it has the entirety of the training set. Maybe I should use something other than a ReLU function in this case? I'm not too sure.

Comment: Using ReLu shouldn't be a problem, try using Sigmoid in the last layer. Also, I have edited my previous answer adding another possible source of errors. Is the training set loaded with the correct label?

Comment: Yes, the training data is loaded with the correct labels. The sigmoid function also did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

few comments:

- Did you check the ground truth in the test data (the shape may be different)
- can you check the output probabilities to see if the predictions are unanimous ? (Btw you don't necessarily need a activation function at the end in this case as the pytorch crossentropy already contains a logsoftmax)
- Did you try conv2d with more filters (like 16,32 or 64)
- The % of error seems fine as in the link you put, the accuracy is around 35%
  It does seems a bit weird not to be able to over-fit.